# why do ints in python arrays are suffixed by

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

In python why do we have numbers as 0., 1., ...? Why not just as 0,1?

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
   [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
   [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
   [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
   [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
   [ 6.,  6.,  6.,  6.],
   [ 7.,  7.,  7.,  7.]])
```

Comment: This looks like an array of floats ;)

Comment: They are representing floating point numbers, so 1. is equivalent to 1.0

Comment: If you want integers do something like this `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], dtype=np.int32)`

Comment: for i in range(8):
    arr[i] = i
 arr
 
 This is the code I used for generating arr. Since the values are fetched from range(8), which are ints, I am thinking that arr is also of type int

Answer (score 0):

It put 1. because it's a float var type and not an int! If you want to convert float to int you can use the function int(): "int(1.)=1"

Comment: for i in range(8):
    arr[i] = i
 arr
 
This is the code I used for generating arr. Since the values are fetched from range(8), which are ints, I am thinking that arr is also of type int

Comment: how do you declare your numpy array?